# Reading data from firebase for android app

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I have been trying to get to understand how `Firebase` works with `Android` apps. I'm trying to read data from the database. I want to get all the child nodes and their corresponding key names of a particular Node. It seems like I can only read data once an event is triggered like a new child added or some value updated. What i want i to read data out without any event happening. Is there some way to this??

Bellow is the code i use in reading!

```
ref0 = myFirebaseRef.child("Users");
ref0.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(data.getKey())+", ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes it is, thanks. I'll check that out... @Andre

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help! My code is actually correct! Just that for some strange reason the System.out.print won't display nothing.. I used Logs and voila!! it displayed the data.. I think Firebase should have named that method something else rather than onDataChange!!!! As it does the job but has a misleading convention. Thanks